# PHP Download only working for files with text in it

Tags: php, file, file-io, download

I want to be able to download files from my server with php. It works so far so good, but only for files with text in it (`.txt` `.php`, so files with simple text (even if there I have an interesting phenomenon, always having one empty line before text starts... ideas why?), but when I try to download an `.jpg` file or an `.exe` it's not working at all (error when trying to open...)

Here is the code I used:

```
<?php

session_start();

$file = basename($_GET['file']);

$path = 'uploads/'.$_SESSION['userid']."/".$file;
?>

<?php
if(!file_exists($path)){
    die("file not found");
} else {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($path);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: how to you call this script? I think your server set header by mime-type for php and txt files.

Comment: It's a link in another php file, like so:
`echo "<a href='download.php?file=".$entry."'>".$entry."</a>\n".'<br/>';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the files have an empty line in is just because there is an empty line in your code

```
...
$path = 'uploads/'.$_SESSION['userid']."/".$file;
?>
                       <--- There's the empty line.
<?php
if(!file_exists($path)){
    die("file not found");
...
```

The solution is to join both your PHP blocks together in to one rather than having two separate blocks.

This also breaks non-text files because they will actually interpret blank lines as data and try and process it.

Comment: amazing, this really works... But can you explain me why?? Why does code have something to do with the content of the file I download

Comment: @user5638730 Basically PHP will only process things that are inside `<?php ?>` tags. Anything outside those tags will be written out (as if you had `echo`ed it) and become part of the file being downloaded. This applies just as much when you have whitespace between the tags as when you have text or HTML.

Comment: So if I would write "hello" between the two lines (where your comment is), I could read hello in my text file?

Comment: @user5638730 Yes, exactly.

Comment: Interesting, never thought about that before, maybe it's just that conspicuous when downloading something.

Comment: @user5638730 That can be the case. When outputting HTML whitespace is generally meaningless so you don't notice any extra but with other types of files it can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Question solved,

I now changed my script to manually react to different types of files, just like so:

```
<?php

session_start();

$filename = basename($_GET['file']);
$filename = 'uploads/'.$_SESSION['userid']."/".$filename;

$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));

switch ($file_extension) {
    case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
    case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
    case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
    case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
    case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
    case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpe": case "jpeg":
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
    default: $ctype="application/force-download";
}

if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    die("NO FILE HERE");
}

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".@filesize($filename));
set_time_limit(0);
@readfile("$filename") or die("File not found.");
```